# Example of a metric.

Tags: metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I am looking for an example of a metric $d(x,y) $ on a vector space $X $ such that is neither a discrete metric nor induced by a norm and satisfies:
$$d(0,ax+(1-a)y)\leq {ad(0,x)}+(1-a)d(0,y),\ \forall x,y \in X, \ \forall  a\in[0,1]$$
But I could not find or construct.  Please give some hint or any example.

Comment: The inequality resembles a concave function very much. Maybe you can look into that?

Answer (score 0):

When $x=(x_1,x_2)\in X = \mathbb{R}^2$, then $f : X\rightarrow
\mathbb{R},\ f(x)=x_1^2-x_2^2$.

Then graph of $f$ is a saddle surface $(S,d_S)$ in $\mathbb{E}^3$
where $d_S$ is a intrinsic metric. Here $d(x,y)
=d_S\bigg((x,f(x)),(y,f(y)) \bigg)$.